# How to select different tensor in Tensorboard Embedding Projector?

Tags: tensorboard

I've saved my trained models(checkpoint and .ckpt.data files) in different directories like a1,a2.Now ,i use

> tensorboard --logdir=/a1

to visualize the model in a1.Do i have to use

> tensorboard --logdir=/a2

to start the project in a2?
Are there any ways to do this thing quickly?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If this any answer below one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. If not, please leave additional detail on your question.

Answer (score 0):

When looking at the manual by running

```
tensorboard --helpfull
```

I see a couple of options that might solve your case:

- the `--logdir` flag accepts several directory paths, separated by a comma, as for example: `tensorboard --logdir name1:/path/to/logs/1,name2:/path/to/logs/2`
- If the first option does not suit you, you may try serving several tensorboard session on different ports. Serving port can be specified with the flag `--port`